# how to set properties and actionEvent on EditText on androud

Tags: android, android-edittext, tablelayout

I passed a EditText view to a table row addView() method. like this:

```
myTablerow.addView(new EditText (this))
```

Q1: How do I set properties like size, colour for the EditText etc

Q2: How do I get the input value from the EditText?

Full code from the author: (P.s. should update in the question instead of my answer)

(It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.)

```
 if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {


        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
        {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            TableRow trheader = new TableRow(this);


            if (i == 0)
                trheader.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#344C58"));
            else
                tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#203F50"));


            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++)
            {
                txtGeneric = new TextView(this);
                TextView txtGenericHeader = new TextView(this);
                //txtGenericHeader.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);


                if (i == 0) {
                    txtGeneric.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

                    for (int z = 0; z < numberOfColumns; z++) {
                        txtGenericHeader.setTextSize(12);
                        txtGenericHeader.setAllCaps(false);
                        //txtGeneric.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#768F9E"));
                        txtGenericHeader.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#768F9E"));
                        txtGenericHeader.setText(cursor.getColumnName(j));
                        txtGenericHeader.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);


                    }
                    trheader.addView(txtGenericHeader);
                }


                txtGeneric.setTextSize(12);
                txtGeneric.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#768F9E"));
                txtGeneric.setText(mArrayList.get(counter++));
                txtGeneric.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);


                tr.addView(txtGeneric);


            }


            tr.addView(new EditText(this));
            tr.addView(new EditText(this));
            table.addView(trheader);
            table.addView(tr);
            cursor.moveToNext();



        }
        db.close();
        sv.addView(table);
        lay.addView(sv);


    }//EOF PARENT IF
```

Answer (score 0):

you may refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText)

Q1: `#setTextColor()` , `#setTextSize()`

Q2: `#getText()`

Comment: I did  dat already but keep getting The specified child already has a parent .You must call removeView() on the child's parent first error. so the only way I get the it working is via that method. I  was actually adding the EditText dyamatically to a tablelayout.

Comment: Could you please post more of your code? seems nothing's wrong with `myTablerow.addView(new EditText (this))`

Comment: i have edited the post, it now include the full code

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for setting the properties.

```
EditText edtText = new EditText(this);
edtText.setTextColor(someColor);
edtText.setTextSize(someSize);
myTablerow.addView(edtText);
```

And for getting the value from EditText you can use.

```
String edtTextValue = edtText.getText().toString();
```